# How to return a string like a zip file in python google app engine?

Tags: python, string, google-app-engine, zip

i need to create a zip file from a string contained in the ndb datastore of Google App Engine, and return it to the user by the web browser. 
I already try to return this string like a text file, using the MIME content-type = application/octet-stream, and it works perfectly.
My idea is to do the same thing using application/zip, but i don't understand if and how i can obtain this results.
Does someone know the solution?

Comment: It seems like you already know how to create a ZIP in memory, and how to set the content-type of the response; what else is it that you need to know?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to create the zip from a string. And the most important thing is that I don't want to store the zip, but direct send it by the browser. I simply succeed to send a string like a text file. I hope that now my problem is clearest.

Comment: I think the solution at the question you posted, it's ok only for the Python environment, but not for the python google appengine environment. But I'll try!!